# Taking Output of to python container and running commands on values

Tags: python, drive

I was wondering if someone could help I'm trying to build a script so I can monitor my HDDs.
What I'm trying to do is use smartmontools to get all the data I need.

What I am trying to build is:

#### Scanner of Drives

```
Scan_of_Drives = os.system('cmd /k smartctl --scan')
print Scan_of_Drives
```

I get this output :

```
/dev/sda -d ata # /dev/sda, ATA device
/dev/csmi0,0 -d ata # /dev/csmi0,0, ATA device
```

Now I'm trying to take the values "sda" and "csmi" (Note if there are more drives I need those too)
and store it in a container so that I can run it with my next code.

which is :
`os.system('cmd /k smartctl -x sda')` (and so on and so forth)

then store that data into a container called "`sda_data`"

I'm sorry if this is out of the norm of questions but I've been trying for like four weeks and I am very new to python which also works to my disadvantage.

I would appreciate any advice or links to websites to help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do anything using `os.system` because it executes the command in a subshell without letting you access much or anything, you can just know if the command succeeded or failed from its return value.

What you want is `subprocess` which is much more flexible, and amongst other things lets you retrieve the text generated by the command (printed to stdout). Here what you're looking for is [subprocess.check_call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) (or the proper combination of arguments to `subprocess.run` on Python 3 though that seems not to be the case).

This way you will get the resulting output as a string, which you can slice and dice in order to retrieve whatever information you need.

An alternative would be to use something like [pySMART](https://pypi.org/project/pySMART/) which wraps smartctl and does the parsing for you, providing a direct programmatic API to what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks I checked out pySMART and it seems it can be a very useful tool although Im going to have to work at it abit but again thank you